# Как VS code из html быстро перейти к классу в css?

Tags: visual-studio-code

То есть я в `html` нашел  какой `class` и хочу сразу найти его описание в `css`

В `dreamweaver` можно было просто нажать <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> и сразу можно было редактировать описание класса.
Но тут такого нет.

Иногда много классов искать в структуре бывает утомительно.

Comment: ставь webstorm, он лучше))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте расширения
CSS Navigation, CSS Peek почитайте инструкции по настройке.

Либо комбинацию <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>